# class method_1 doesn't pass the test, but it works in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, specifications

I have two following models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :tasks, inverse_of: :project
 attr_accessible :tasks_attributes

 def method_1
  tasks.map |t|
    t.name
  end
 end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :project, inverse_of: :tasks

 attr_accessible :name

 validates :name, presence: true
end
```

i'm writing the test for project_spec.rb. I test the association and validations, they are all fine. but somehow i can't pass the test of method_1. I changed method_1 code as followed, just to check. the result i got is [nil], ie tasks.first is nil. I don't know what I'm missing.

```
 def method_1
  [tasks.first]
 end
```

my test code is,

```
...
let(:project) do
   build_stubbed(:project, :project_data)
end

describe "#method_1" do
 before do
   project.stub_chain(:task, :name).and_return("task A")
 end
 subject {project.method_1} 
  it "should be the name of the task of the project" do
    should eq ["task A"]
  end   
end
```

when i run localhost:3000, it has the same problem. but in rails console, the method_1 works fine too. Anyone can help? it bothers me for days.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `tasks.collect(&:name)`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some comments that might help:

- `method_1` relies on `tasks`, but you've stubbed `task` (singular), so it's not having any effect.
- perhaps `method_1` works in the Rails console because you have a tasks related to the project in your development database
- problems using localhost:3000 could be due to any number of things, since you don't use model methods directly through the web